# Physical applications based on mathematical model of non-instantaneous impulsive evolution equations

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-equations, operator-theory, applied-mathematics

In this paperhttps://www.researchgate.net/publication/269404928_Periodic_solutions_for_nonlinear_evolution_equations_with_non-instantaneous_impulses authors prove the existence and stability of the solutions of the following  first order  linear non-instantaneous impulsive evolution equation:

$u'(t)=Au(t)~~ t\in[s_i,t_{i+1}],\,i\in\mathbb{N_0}:=\{0,1,2,...\}$

$u(t_i^+)=(E+B_i)u(t_i^-),\,\,i\in\mathbb{N}:=\{1,2,...\},$

$u(t)=(E+B_i)u(t_i^-),\,\, t\in(t_i,s_i],\,\, i\in\mathbb{N},$

$u(s_i^+)=u(s_i^-),\,\, i\in\mathbb{N}$

where $A:D(A)\subseteq X\rightarrow X$ is the Generator of a $C_0$-semigroup $\{T(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ on a Banach space $X$ with a norm $\|.\|,\,B_i:X\rightarrow X,\,i\in\mathbb{N}$ is bounded linear operator,the sequences $\{s_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N_0}}$ and $\{t_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N_0}}$ are satisfied with the relation $t_i<s_i<t_{i+1},\,i\in\mathbb{N}$ and set $t_o=s_0=0$. Moreover $E$ denotes the standard identity.

Now, I am motivated to learn about the physical phenomena which can be described by this mathematical model. Therefore, please guide me to the literature where I can find the application of the above mentioned system of non-instantaneous impulsive evolution equations.

Comment: It seems to me that the party who should answer this question is the author of whatever paper you are referring to. Of course, it might be argued that the referees should have asked this question, too.

Comment: I am sorry for some reasons, the link wasn't there, but I have edited it now.